# Custom URI in Android devices and iOS devices

Tags: android, deep-linking, custom-url

I had a problem with Custom URI.

Custom URI : scheme:\music\album\tamil\albumID

When I mail this as text it appears as link in iOS devices as link but not in Android devices.

When user select/click the Cutom URI it should navigate to my app and have to show the appropriate content.

This custom URI is passed from one website's button click. In iOS device its react as link not in Android devices.

The web end passing the Custom URI as below

**href="scheme://music/tamil/album/albumID"**

As a Android developer what should I do to resolve this ?.

Or from web end how to pass the Custom URI as link?.

Answer (score 0):

I think your mail provider/client is responsible for this behaviour. Gmail for example removes custom URIs and replaces `href` links from `<a>` tags. This may be for security reasons, not sure why. I suggest you to use "http" as scheme. Then Android will prompt you to open with browser or your app. Add intent filter as below example.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

You may also add a `android:host`, and `android:path` or `android:pathPrefix` if needed.

Another option is to use a redirect 302. An example for php is below. The drawback is this will open the browser at first.

`<a href="openmyapp.php?cat=music&albumID=9128">`

```
<?php
    header("Location: scheme://". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    exit;
?>
```